# Pandas fill missing value with most common value with filter?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

Given a dataframe with two columns like the following:

```
| user_id | preference_id |
|---------|---------------|
| 1       | 1             |
| 1       | 2             |
| 1       | None          |
| 2       | 1             |
| 3       | 2             |
| 3       | 2             |
| 3       | None          |
```

How can I fill is the missing values in `preference_id` with the most frequent value for that `user_id`? My current solution includes looping over all unique `user_id`s that have at least one missing value for `preference_id` and at least one instance of `preference_id` with data:

```
# Find all rows where preference_id is missing
pref_na = df.loc[df.preference_id.isna()]

# Find all users that have at least one missing and one not missing
# value for preference_id
users = df.loc[
  (~df.preference_id.isna()) & (df.user_id.isin(pref_na))
]

for id in users.user_id.unique():
    # Find most common preference_id for a user
    top_pref = df.loc[
        (df.user_id == id) & (~df.preference_id.isna()),
        ['preference_id']
    ]
    if top_pref.shape[0] == 0:
        continue
    top_pref = top_pref.preference_id.mode()[0]

    # Fill in missing prefs with top_pref
    df.loc[
        (df.user_id == id) & (df.preference_id.isna()),
        'preference_id'] = top_pref
```

Is there a native or vectorized way to accomplish this?

## Edit

Here's an example where the suggestion by @anky_91 breaks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'preference_id': [1, 2, None, None, 2, 2, None]
})
```

That is, one of the `user_id` records only has missing `preference_id`s

## Edit #2

After experimenting with the solution by @anky_91 I was able to solve the edge case posted above by first filtering out users that only had missing values (and hence, users that I can't extrapolate the missing preference_id for):

```
# Remove edge cases
ids = df.groupby('user_id').preference_id.count()\
    .where(lambda x: x > 0).dropna().to_frame().reset_index()

# User anky_91 solution
ids.groupby('user_id').preference_id.transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
```

There's likely a more efficient and elegant way to do the first step, but that will do. The slow part is the second step, so I'm okay with that form of step #1.

Comment: What if there are two (or more) most common values?

Comment: `top_pref = top_pref.preference_id.mode()[0]` If there are multiple prefs with the same frequency, I just take any one of them. This doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
s=df.groupby('user_id')['preference_id'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
df.preference_id=df.preference_id.fillna(s)
print(df)
```

---

```
   user_id  preference_id
0        1            1.0
1        1            2.0
2        1            1.0
3        2            1.0
4        3            2.0
5        3            2.0
6        3            2.0
```

Another way:

```
m=(df.groupby('user_id')['preference_id'].apply(lambda x: x.mode(dropna=False).iat[0])
.reset_index(name='Mode'))
df.merge(m,on='user_id')
```

---

```
   user_id  preference_id  Mode
0        1            1.0   1.0
1        1            2.0   1.0
2        1            NaN   1.0
3        2            NaN   NaN
4        3            2.0   2.0
5        3            2.0   2.0
6        3            NaN   2.0
```

Comment: This looks very promising. However, the value sent to the lambda seems to be a series with a single `preference_id`. There are instances where a given `user_id` has 5 prefs with a value and only one with `nan`, but the lambda is being passed exactly that `nan`, so `x.mode().iat[0]` returns a `index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira it groups `user_id` before that, can you elaborate on the OP stating this and with an example?

Comment: Posted an example